# Show partial page within a view page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've a recommender view model

**Recommender View Model**

```
public class RecommenderViewModel
{
    public string ProName { get; set; }
    public int? OdId { get; set; }
    public int? OrdId { get; set; }
    public string CusName { get; set; }
    public string CatName { get; set; }
    public int catId { get; set; }
    public string SubCatName { get; set; }
    public int subcatId { get; set; }
    public string SubSubCatName { get; set; }
    public int subsubcatId { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        private Shopping db = new Shopping();
        string userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        List<RecommenderViewModel> model = new List<RecommenderViewModel>();
        var innerJoinQuery = (from pro in db.Products
                              join sup in db.OrderDetails on pro.ProductId equals sup.ProductID
                              join ord in db.Orders on sup.OrderId equals ord.OrderId
                              join cus in db.Users on ord.UserId equals cus.Id where cus.Id == userID
                              join cat in db.Categories on pro.CategoryId equals cat.CategoryId
                              join subcat in db.SubCategories on pro.SubCategoryId equals subcat.SubCatId
                              join subsubcat in db.SubSubCategories on pro.SubSubCategoryId equals subsubcat.SubSubCatId

                              select new
                              {   
                                  proName = pro.Name,
                                  odId = sup.OrderDetailId,
                                  ordId = ord.OrderId,
                                  cusName = cus.FirstName,
                                  catName = cat.Name,
                                  catId = cat.CategoryId,
                                  subcatName = subcat.SubCatName,
                                  subcatId = subcat.SubCatId,
                                  subsubcatName = subsubcat.SubSubCatName,
                                  subsubcatId = subsubcat.SubSubCatId
                              }).ToList();//convert to List


        foreach (var item in innerJoinQuery)
        {
            model.Add(new RecommenderViewModel()
            {
                ProName = item.proName,
                OdId = item.odId,
                OrdId = item.ordId,
                CusName = item.cusName,
                CatName = item.catName,
                catId = item.catId,
                SubCatName = item.subcatName,
                subcatId = item.subcatId,
                SubSubCatName = item.subsubcatName,
                subsubcatId = item.subsubcatId
                //recProName = q 
            });
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

From the above Index Action and queries from RecommenderController. I get the desired result that I wanted. [Picture of result](http://s9.postimg.org/71egxalwv/Untitled.png) in the view.

Now I have another View Page of ProductDetails which display the details of a product like ProductName, Price, Quantity, Description and I want to create a Partial View of Index() and display it within the product details view page which is a strongly-type view and uses **@model Project.Models.Product**.

**Product.cs**

```
public partial class Product {
   public int ProductId {get; set;}
   public int ProductName {get; set;}
   public int ProductDescription {get; set;}
   public int ProductPrice {get; set;}
   public int ProductIdQuantity {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: If I get you correctly, if you want to display product details along with recommend products for similar category like amazon or other retail website does?

Comment: @user1672994 yes. but in my code all I'm doing is getting the previous purchase record of the logged in user and matching the product id and getting the category of that purchased product and showing him more products from category

Comment: @user1672994 later on i will be doing this too, using cookies I guess. I will try to recommend him the products that he is watching, i guess i will have to store his session or cookies for that purpose.

Comment: You can put the viewed items either in session or DB (that will be your choice). Now to answer your question, you can create a partial view for the index which will accept the int? product id to show all vs selected product. I will post the answer in few mins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a ChildAction and Partial view for it.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult RetrieveProductDetails(int? productId)
{
}
```

Now, from your Index action will return the index view which will render the view

```
@Html.RenderAction("RetrieveProductDetails", "Home");
```

You can use the same logic in your ProductDetails page with only difference is that you will pass the product id

```
@Html.RenderAction("RetrieveProductDetails", "Home", new { @productId = Model.ProductId });
```

Comment: I don't think that's a solution. I have Index Action in Recommender Controller and ProductDetails Action in Home Controller.

Comment: RenderAction's second parameter is Controller name. So change it to `@Html.RenderAction("RetrieveProductDetails", "Recommender")`

Comment: Thanks man. I got it working. It was giving an error "canno implicitly convert void to object" then I wrote it like this
@{Html.RenderAction("RetrieveProductDetails", "Recommender");}
and it worked.

Comment: Any idea regarding showing recommended products by user browsing history or his recently viewed products ? or should i ask another question ?

Comment: You should build your system in such a way that it audits into persistant storage (can be DB) for product viewed by user. So while showing you can query to get the recently viewed or browsing history.

Comment: Did the answer given up for partial view resolved your queries?

Comment: any example ? I can create another table "RecentlyViewed" which will have columns "productId" recently viewed products and "userId" of user who is visiting. But how will I catch his activity of visiting the page and storing it in DB ?

Comment: When user is visiting the product details page then you know the product id and user id. Create a table which have ProductId, UserId, DateVisited and other fields.

Comment: can we discuss it further in chat ?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to create a chat. Will you ?

Comment: Join [this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/97055/user3223395667-and-user1672994) room